# Displaying last page of data with datatable()

Tags: javascript, r, dt

In the `DT` library `datatable()` will draw the first page (default max of 10 rows) of a table

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

I have checked the [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) but could not find a suitable example for displaying a specific page (for example, the last page) in a table.  I suppose this must be written with a Javascript callback.

> callback   the body of a JavaScript callback function with the argument
>   table to be applied to the DataTables instance (i.e. table)

This callback, for example, will draw the second page in the table:

```
  datatable(head(iris, 30), callback = JS('table.page("next").draw(false);'))
```

How would one draw the last page, or a different, `x`th  page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table.page("last")` seems to work:

```
datatable(head(iris, 30), rownames=F,
          callback = JS('table.page("last").draw(false);'))
```

[image]

The relevant API reference is here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()

I included the `rownames = F` option since that was an issue with the other answer, but it's not required

Answer (score 1):

`table.fnPageChange( 'last' );`

Should take you to the last page as stated [here](http://datatables.net/api#fnPageChange)

Comment: Thanks for the reference

Comment: This code, however, does not work with some other options, for example: `datatable(iris, callback = JS('table.fnPageChange("last");'), rownames = FALSE)`   Is it that row names must be displayed?

Comment: @the_darkside sorry but I do not understand R and what I suggested was based on JS. :(

Comment: thanks, but this does not produce the desired result, even with rownames - still showing the first